# Django forms.validation error not showing

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a registration form using djangos built in User.  I'd like to have a password field and then a second field to verify the passwords match (keep in mind this is a new user so no password exists in the db yet).  I think I'm really close and it seems like I need the validation error to pass from the form to the view.  The form just clears our the passwords...and leaves the remaining entered data, but no validation error is thrown at all.  Any thoughts and help is greatly appreciated!

**Form**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    ver_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': ' confirm password'}))
    ver_email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': ' confirm email'}))

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'password',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'email')

    def clean(self):
        all_clean_data = super().clean()
        clean_email = all_clean_data['email']
        clean_ver_email = all_clean_data['ver_email']
        clean_password = all_clean_data['password']
        clean_ver_password = all_clean_data['ver_password']

        if clean_email != clean_ver_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Emails do not match")
        if clean_password != clean_ver_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")

        return all_clean_data
```

**View**

```
def register(request):

    registered = False
    newregister = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save(update_fields=['username','password','first_name','last_name','email'])

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True
            newregister = True
            return render(request, 'dai_members_app/login.html',
                                    {'user_form':user_form,
                                      'profile_form':profile_form,
                                      'registered':registered})
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not returning anything if the forms are not valid. It is only returning a response if the forms are valid, which is why "The form just clears our the passwords...and leaves the remaining entered data"

Secondly, your view is unusual because normally a form view handles both the GET request (displaying the blank form) and the POST request (validating and saving the incoming data). Unless you have a good reason to do something different, you should stick to standard Django patterns at least while you are learning the basics.

Please see the example in the Django documentation for a functional view for form handling:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-view

It's worth noting that Django already provides a form for user signup: `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`. You should use this rather than rolling your own unless you need to do something special, which it doesn't look like.

The tutorial here is also a good starting point: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html